# Calculate best Path in Hexagonal Polygon

Tags: algorithm

I want to get the best Path for this polygon:
[image]

I want do draw one solid line that follows **all** lines in the HEXAGOn (also the inner ones) in an optimal way without using the line twice.(I think almost impossible)
How to Calculate the best shortest Path?

Comment: This is the bridge problem of Konigsberg first solved by Euler. All vertices should have even number of edges connected to it so that you can trace it with a single line (Euler circuit). Or.. i guess max two vertices are allowed have odd number of edges as mandatory start and end points (Euler path). In this case all 6 vertices except for the center one have odd number of edges connected. So no...

Comment: OK found it thank you. thought already that this is impossible. But lets exclude the requirement that all points can just used one time. Lets say they can used multiple times how could i calculate that? we could then just try the best way out by testing all possibilitys...

Comment: Do you mean the shortest rope that can cover all the edges..? I guess 14 edge length long but again i suggest you delete this question and repost accordingly so that more people can see.

Comment: Yeah shortest rope would match it pretty well. do you think this headline will do it:
"Shortest rope to cover all edges of an Polygon"

Comment: Yes sure.. But add the `graph-theory` tag alongside `algorithm`. Also you may post it to [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) department.